# How do I prevent rails_admin gem from pluralizing certain labels in the navigation sidebar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

Anyone who's used rails_admin gem might have noticed that the labels in the navigation sidebar are always pluralized.

Is there anyway to prevent this for specific models?

Answer (score 5):

In the README:

> You probably want to change the name of the navigation_label. This can
>   be easily achieved with the 'navigation_label' method of the parent
>   model.
>
> Added to previous example:

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base
  rails_admin do
    navigation_label 'League related'   
  end 
end
```

Does that fix your problem?

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem, the navigation label is there to let you create nested menus. The labels are still pluralized. I have a feeling this can't be resolved after looking at the code. I can live with it.

Comment: Is there any way I can translate (I18n) navigation_label text?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass in a `label_plural` parameter in the rails admin initializer

```
config.model Thing do
  label_plural "Thing"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this. Here's how:

- Create views/rails_admin/main/_navigation.html.haml
- Copy and paste code from the equivalent file within the rails_admin gem source code
- replace all instances of `label_plural` with `label`

So the following would change from:

```
= link_to(model.label_plural, list_path(:model_name => model.abstract_model.to_param))
```

to:

```
= link_to(model.label, list_path(:model_name => model.abstract_model.to_param))
```

This is fine to do since the label and label_plural are quite similar as you can see:

```
register_instance_option(:label) do
  @label ||= abstract_model.model.model_name.human(:default => abstract_model.model.model_name.demodulize.underscore.humanize)
end

register_instance_option(:label_plural) do
  @label_plural ||= abstract_model.model.model_name.human(:count => 2, :default => label.pluralize)
end
```

Now if I want a pluralized label I just specify it in my model's rails_admin block.